# A conflict has been detected with the following binding: https:*:443:tfspoc.com:WebHosting::sni. See the log for additional details

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I was trying to upgrade my TFS 2018 configuration with the latest RC2 of Azure DevOps Server version. In the verification window the configuration throws the below error:

> A conflict has been detected with the following binding:
>   https:*:443:tfspoc.com:WebHosting:7092C7C5C3BD500731A769270E24B839829952EB:sni.
>   See the log for additional details.

Whereas I was using the same cert for the previous configuration. The log file also does not have any other information than the above. Not sure what is the conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by uninstalling and reinstalling IIS and WAS using poweshell command:

Uninstall-WindowsFeature

Assuming that, while upgrade Azure DevOps Server 2019 RC2 missed to remove the binding some place.